# How can I replace a word with asterisks in it?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep

I'm trying to replace a word with asterisks in it, like:

```
*vip*4567*39384
```

I've tried this and it failed:

```
grep -lr -e "*v3434*i2802*p5348" . | xargs sed -i "s/*v3434*i2802*p5348/hdjelros362/g"
```

Any help on this would be great.

Comment: Escape the `*` as `\*`

Answer (score 1):

Because this is a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), the asterisk is being interpreted as a [Kleene star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star). So just *escape* it with a back slash:

```
\*v3434\*i2802\*p5348
```